# Correct way to protect .htacces file

Tags: .htaccess

I came across a [blog article](http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/05/20/improve-site-security-by-protecting-htaccess-files/) that indicates that .htaccess files should be protected but I am a little confused as to which part of this is the correct way to implement this security. Here is the snippet:

```
<Files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
Order Deny,Allow
#order allow,deny
Deny from all
satisfy all
</Files>
```

should it be `Order Deny, Allow` or `Order Allow, Deny`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `Order Deny,Allow` (note the lack of space).

The [Order directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order) defines the order which permission checks should be performed, so `Order Deny,Allow` says “check the `Deny` directives before checking `Allow` directives”.